# In Candy Crush, why is there no quest option after level 305?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

Completed level 305, and for the first time there is no play quests option.

I'm not on facebook and haven't been in 8 months.

I tried shutting down my Android and turning it back on... nope.

I tried turning off wifi... nope.

It's been 14 hours since I completed level 305.

What's up?

Comment: What game is this? Please edit your question and its tags to reflect include this rather important piece of information

Comment: I edited the question to add Candy Crush, but I don't understand the tag thing. What am I supposed to put there? Thank you PP.

Comment: It looks like my tag has been edited, but it wasn't edited by me. Thank you to person who corrected it for me.

Comment: @Jenny You put the game the glitch is about in the tag.

Comment: But I still don't know why I'm not getting the quest option. On my last android phone I was near the 500 level and I never ran into this. Googling the answer is getting me no where. I started this game for a free way to wind down in the evenings. I'm not going to pay to keep playing.

Comment: @Studoku... Does it say Candy Crush, now? It does on my end. I think Frank must have fixed it.

Comment: Okay. It offered quests for a few hours and then... the option disappeared again.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197246/not-offered-candy-crush-quest-anymore